# How to track active tab in a Multi level nextjs navbar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

How to track active tab (yellow highlighted) and show links corressponding links (red highlighted) ?
I am creating a multilevel navbar in nextjs i tried using on mouseEnter and leave but things didnt worked out as expected.

I need help for the following usecases:-

1. i have 3 options (yellow boxes) on hover over any  of these the red box or links inside the red box should be changed accordingly.
2. should be easier to shows for mobile devices where it becomes
   solutions > automation (dropdown toggle) > automation links list

Trying to replicate the feature found at https://stripe.com/in [image]

I have replicated the code from https://github.com/Sattu2806/GitHub-Clone
on mousehover and mouseout event handleter on the yellow highlighted links didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-level Navigation with Dynamic Links and Highlights in Next.js

Building a navigation bar like Stripe's in Next.js requires juggling state management, event handling, and conditional rendering. Here's how to tackle the key aspects:

1. Tracking Active Tab:

State Management: Instead of "Redux or recoil," consider a generic "state library" to store the currently selected tab's ID or index.
2. Hover and Click Events:

Interaction Events: Replace "onMouseEnter" and "onMouseLeave" with generic "hover" and "leave" events, or consider using "click" for mobile devices. Update the state with the corresponding option ID/index on interaction.
3. Highlighting Links:

Conditional Rendering: Render the "red box" and its links only when the active state matches the current option. Use "if" statements or similar conditional logic within your JSX.
4. Mobile-friendliness:

Dropdown Toggle: For mobile, consider a "toggle button" revealing the "red box" links for the chosen option. This improves tap accessibility and reduces clutter.
5. Additional Tips:

Performance: Optimize rendering by memoizing functions to avoid unnecessary updates.
Accessibility: Ensure keyboard navigation and screen reader compatibility for the navigation.
Example Code Structure:

> const options = [...]; // Array of navigation options with labels and
> links (optional) const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(''); //
> State for storing selected tab
>
> function handleInteraction(optionId) {   setActiveTab(optionId); }
>
> function renderLinks(option) {   // Conditional logic to render links
> only for the active tab   ... }
>
> return (   
> {options.map(option => (
> <div
> className={`option-box ${activeTab === option.id ? 'active' : ''}`}
> onClick={() => handleInteraction(option.id)}
> >
> {option.label}
> {renderLinks(option)}
>
> ))}    );